# OnEdit - not deleting all data

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have the below code which works fine except instead of deleting all requested data it deletes only a few lines. If i have 10 lines that are equal to NO, only about 3 or 4 get deleted.

Code does work. Can't work out why it doesn't delete all the equals to NO

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName('D2D MACRO'); // change to your own
var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var row in values){
if (values[row][0] == 'NO'){
 s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not complete - where are you ending your `for` loop and `if` statement?

Comment: Ross this is how I got the code. Could you suggest please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you posted is that you are iterating while you delete rows. This causes that the rows are reindexed as you iterate over them and, as a result, some of them are not targeted with your loop.

A solution for this is to iterate in reverse order:

```
function onEdit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

    for (var i=values.length-1; i>= 0; i--)
        if (values[i][0] == 'NO')
            s.deleteRow(i+1);
}
```